# how To get a large data in Jquerydatatable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

I am new in MVC application, I have handled the large data in Jquery datatable Server side script working fine when all data loaded(ex: Select the all Records in particular table).

If I make manual filter (ex: `Select * from xxx where zzz=yyy`) then I am not able to send parameters to controller action.

Please find the below script.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger
    var oTable = $('#PartUpdate').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "Test/AjaxHandler",
        data: $.param({ 'b':'Mani'}),
        "bProcessing": true,
        buttons: [
                  'csv', 'excel', 'print'
        ],
        "aoColumns": [
            {
                "sName": "ID",
                "bSearchable": false,
                "bSortable": false,
                "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                    return '<a href=\"Company/Details/' + oObj.aData[0] + '\">View</a>';
                }
            },
            { "sName": "UserName" },
            { "sName": "FullName" },
            { "sName": "EmailId" }
        ]   
    });
});
```

Comment: Show also controller code.

Comment: Use Entity framework with the skip and take for managing paging.  Or if you want to use along with the query then use limit and offset such that you will only get a slice of data to display once.